# Dialogflow Mega Agent not working in messenger

Tags: facebook, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

I am having a problem integrating the mega agent of Dialogflow to FB messenger. It is not working although I have already followed the same steps in connecting a single agent to Facebook messenger.

The single-agent connection to FB works perfectly just the Mega Agent is the one I'm having trouble with

Do you guys encounter this same issue? If so how did you solved it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is okay now I just have to use the old Webhook URL of Dialogflow